# Offer introductory price only to some subscription buyers

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app in the Apple app-store where some extra features are offered through a couple of one time in-app purchases. I want to transfer that to a subscription model. To make it more acceptable for those who already bought the old IAP I want to give them the first year free. However, I have problems implementing this.

Alternative 1:
Create an "Introductory offer" (one year free) for the new subscribed IAP. But I can't see a way to control who gets that offer, which means all new buyers will benefit from it.

Alternative 2:
Create a "Promotional offer". But that is only meant for getting old subscribers back. So there is no way for a new buyer to use that offer (I think).

Alternative 3:
Create two completely different IAP, one with an introductory offer and one without. That would work, but is a clunky solution that I want to avoid.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Hello! How did you manage to achieve this? I am facing a similar issue where we want to have some introductory offers only for specific users.

Comment: I went for alternative 3. I have two different IAP with different introductory offers. I choose which one to present depending on if the user has the old version. It has worked reasonably well over the last year.

Comment: Sten, Have you submitted new versions of the app since this conversation? Is Apple still cool with your approach? I have similar need to @Efraim

Comment: I have updated the app many times without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to change someone who bought an IAP with no expiry date to a subscription. Doing this will likely lead to Apple intervening and unlisting your app.

They bought your IAP with the understanding it was an eternal licence. You can only bill NEW customers on a subscription.

You’ll need to keep record of those who purchased the IAP and new customers who purchase a subscription.

Comment: I am not changing their existing IAP, they will be able to continue to use that. What I want to do is to give them an incitement to upgrade to the new subscription which will contain more. My question was not whether it was legal or not (it is) but how to do it technically.